# x86 instruction meaning

Tags: assembly, x86, att, addressing-mode

I'm running through some code right now on gdb and I have no clue what these two instructions actually do.  If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

```
add  -0x2c(%ebp, %ebx, 4), %eax
cmp  %eax, -0x28(%ebp, %ebx, 4)
```

Comment: First off, I'd turn off the cruddy AT&T syntax: `set disassembly-flavor intel`

Comment: See also the [AT&T syntax tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info) for more details on the syntax, and links to more docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x86 assembly is usually much easier to understand when you write it in Intel syntax instead of AT&T syntax.

In Intel syntax it would be:

```
add eax,[ebp+4*ebx-0x2C]
cmp [ebp+4*ebx-0x28],eax
```

The first instruction (`add`) adds the value of word stored in the memory address `[ebp+4*ebx-0x2C]` to the value of `eax`, and stores the sum in `eax`.

The second instruction (`cmp`) compares `eax` with `[ebp+4*ebx-0x28]` by subtracting the value of `eax` from the value of the word stored in the memory address `[ebp+4*ebx-0x28]`, and sets flags (`OF`, `SF`, `ZF`, `AF`, `PF`, `CF`) accordingly but does not save the result anywhere. `cmp` is exactly the same as `sub`, the only difference being the fact that in `sub` the result is saved, in `cmp` not.

The type of comparison is usually created in the form a conditional jump. In x86 assembly there are a lot of conditional jumps and whether they branch depends on the values of the flags.

Comment: Sorry >.< I just started doing this stuff within the past week so I didn't know how to change between syntax's and such.  This does help a lot though.  How do I exactly check the value of the flag?

Comment: [Intel and AT&T syntaxes](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm) A conditional jump after `cmp` jumps to somewhere else in the code if the condition is met. If not, then the execution continues on the next instruction (no jump). There are other possible ways too (a hash table with flags as keys), but conditional jumps solve all the cases. Note that in Intel and AT&T syntaxes the order of operands is reversed, in Intel its `dest,src` whereas in AT&T it's `src,dest`. This affects `cmp` too. See [Intel x86 jump quick ref.](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html).

Answer (score 1):

That's AT&T assembly syntax.  Those addressing modes are a bit weird looking, but in pseudocode, they mean:

```
eax = *(ebp + ebx*4 - 0x2c)
```

and

```
compare eax to *(ebp + ebx*4 - 0x28)
```

Here's a link with [complete explanation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Address_operand_syntax).